# How to update object value on the cmp file from the Javascript file?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

```
<aura:attribute
    name="updatePaanV"
    type="Paan_List__c"
    default="{
      sobjectName : 'Paan_List__c',
      Name: '',
      Paan_Color__c:'',
      Paan_Description__c: '',
      Paan_Img_Url__c: '',
      Paan_Price__c: '',
      Paan_Quantity__c: ''}"
  />
```

This is an object, I am updating the object values form js controller file like this:

```
component.set("v.updatePaanV", responseValue);
```

I want to show the updated value instantly in the component file. But it is not showing. The fields are blank.

```
      type="text"
      id="max"
      aura:id="paanUpdateForm"
      class="textInput"
      messageWhenValueMissing="Please enter Paan Name"
      value="{!v.insertNewPaanV.Name}"
      label="Name"
      required="true"
      onchange="{!c.fieldValidateForUpdate}"
    />
```

For example this field, I like to update instantly form the js controller file. But, the updated value is not showing in the cmp file. Please help me out, thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "not showing in the cmp file". Do you mean it's not appearing in the UI? Do you have code (or some of the code) from the Apex controller you're calling that you get `responseValue` from? Is the return type also `Paan_List__c`? It might help to also see a bit more of the code from the US controller.

Comment: also it looks like you assign value to "updatePaanV" while you are using "insertNewPaanV" in light:input

Comment: Thank you for your fix.